# SYMFONY 5 - Form EntityType doesn't take the id in the database but the name

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with Symfony. I code a form to choose a school.
In my school entity, I have the identifier, the name and the address.
The form contains a selection list with the identifier as the value and the name of the school as the label.
But when I click on submit and when I go to my database, the name of the school appears in the school identifier in the student table and not the school identifier.

My controller

```
/**
     * @Route("/eleve/inscription/agence", name="eleve.agence")
     */
    public function choixAgence(Request $request)
    {
        $eleve = $this->security->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(EleveChoixAgenceType::class, $eleve);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->em->persist($eleve);
            $this->em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('eleve.index');
        }

        return $this->render('eleve/choixAgence.html.twig', [
            'eleve' => $eleve,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

My School Form type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('codeAgence', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Agence::class,
                'label' => 'Agence',
                'required' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
```

And my Form.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title "Inscription" %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Choix agence</h1>
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{ form_row(form.codeAgence) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
        <button class="btn btn-success">Valider</button>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I don't understand why the school name go into the database instead of the id

Thank you guys for your help

[EDIT]
My School Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\AgenceRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AgenceRepository::class)
 */
class Agence
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nomAgence;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $adresseAgence;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Forfait::class, mappedBy="agence")
     */
    private $forfaits;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->forfaits = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNomAgence(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomAgence;
    }

    public function setNomAgence(string $nomAgence): self
    {
        $this->nomAgence = $nomAgence;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresseAgence(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresseAgence;
    }

    public function setAdresseAgence(string $adresseAgence): self
    {
        $this->adresseAgence = $adresseAgence;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nomAgence;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Forfait[]
     */
    public function getForfaits(): Collection
    {
        return $this->forfaits;
    }

    public function addForfait(Forfait $forfait): self
    {
        if (!$this->forfaits->contains($forfait)) {
            $this->forfaits[] = $forfait;
            $forfait->addAgence($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeForfait(Forfait $forfait): self
    {
        if ($this->forfaits->removeElement($forfait)) {
            $forfait->removeAgence($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

[2d Edit]

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EleveRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=EleveRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("mail")
 */
class Eleve implements UserInterface,\Serializable
{
    const LUNETTE = [
        'Non' => 'Non',
        'Oui' => 'Oui'
    ];

    const MODE_REGLEMENT = [
        'Carte Bancaire' => 'Carte Bancaire',
        'Chèque' => 'Chèque'
    ];

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email( message = "L'email '{{ value }}' n'est pas un email valide." )
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     max=50,
     *     min="8",
     *     minMessage="Le mot de passe doit être supérieur ou égal à 8 caractères")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $mdp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $dateNaiss;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     * @Assert\Length(max=10)
     */
    private $tel;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     * @Assert\Length(max=10)
     */
    private $telParent;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(max=100)
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $ville;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
     * @Assert\Length(max=5)
     */
    private $cp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $paysNaiss;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $depNaiss;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $villeNaiss;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3)
     * @Assert\Length(max=3)
     */
    private $lunette;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $statutSocial;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(max=100)
     */
    private $lycee;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $modeReglement;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $nomSociete;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\Length(max=100)
     */
    private $adresseSociete;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $metier;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Piecesjointes::class, mappedBy="eleve")
     */
    private $piecesjointes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=2)
     */
    private $codeAgence;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=2)
     */
    private $codeForfait;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->forfaits = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->piecesjointes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): self
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMdp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mdp;
    }

    public function setMdp(string $mdp): self
    {
        $this->mdp = $mdp;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateNaiss(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateNaiss;
    }

    public function setDateNaiss(\DateTimeInterface $dateNaiss): self
    {
        $this->dateNaiss = $dateNaiss;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    public function setTel(string $tel): self
    {
        $this->tel = $tel;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelParent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->telParent;
    }

    public function setTelParent(string $telParent): self
    {
        $this->telParent = $telParent;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    public function setAdresse(string $adresse): self
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVille(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ville;
    }

    public function setVille(string $ville): self
    {
        $this->ville = $ville;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->cp;
    }

    public function setCp(string $cp): self
    {
        $this->cp = $cp;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaysNaiss(): ?string
    {
        return $this->paysNaiss;
    }

    public function setPaysNaiss(string $paysNaiss): self
    {
        $this->paysNaiss = $paysNaiss;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDepNaiss(): ?string
    {
        return $this->depNaiss;
    }

    public function setDepNaiss(string $depNaiss): self
    {
        $this->depNaiss = $depNaiss;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVilleNaiss(): ?string
    {
        return $this->villeNaiss;
    }

    public function setVilleNaiss(string $villeNaiss): self
    {
        $this->villeNaiss = $villeNaiss;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLunette(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lunette;
    }

    public function setLunette(string $lunette): self
    {
        $this->lunette = $lunette;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatutSocial(): ?string
    {
        return $this->statutSocial;
    }

    public function setStatutSocial(string $statutSocial): self
    {
        $this->statutSocial = $statutSocial;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLycee(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lycee;
    }

    public function setLycee(string $lycee): self
    {
        $this->lycee = $lycee;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getModeReglement(): ?string
    {
        return $this->modeReglement;
    }

    public function setModeReglement(string $modeReglement): self
    {
        $this->modeReglement = $modeReglement;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNomSociete(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomSociete;
    }

    public function setNomSociete(string $nomSociete): self
    {
        $this->nomSociete = $nomSociete;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresseSociete(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresseSociete;
    }

    public function setAdresseSociete(string $adresseSociete): self
    {
        $this->adresseSociete = $adresseSociete;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMetier(): ?string
    {
        return $this->metier;
    }

    public function setMetier(string $metier): self
    {
        $this->metier = $metier;

        return $this;
    }

    /* --------------- */

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->mail,
            $this->mdp
        ]);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->mail,
            $this->mdp
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ['ROLE_ELEVE'];
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->getMail();
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->getMdp();
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Piecesjointes[]
     */
    public function getPiecesjointes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->piecesjointes;
    }

    public function addPiecesjointe(Piecesjointes $piecesjointe): self
    {
        if (!$this->piecesjointes->contains($piecesjointe)) {
            $this->piecesjointes[] = $piecesjointe;
            $piecesjointe->setEleve($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePiecesjointe(Piecesjointes $piecesjointe): self
    {
        if ($this->piecesjointes->removeElement($piecesjointe)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($piecesjointe->getEleve() === $this) {
                $piecesjointe->setEleve(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeAgence(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codeAgence;
    }

    public function setCodeAgence(string $codeAgence): self
    {
        $this->codeAgence = $codeAgence;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeForfait(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codeForfait;
    }

    public function setCodeForfait(?string $codeForfait): self
    {
        $this->codeForfait = $codeForfait;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your School entity class?

Comment: Yeah sure, i forgot to post it

Comment: Can you post the entity for which this FormType has been built?

```code
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('codeAgence', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Agence::class,
                'label' => 'Agence',
                'required' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

```

The one containing the property: codeAgence

Comment: I just did it, in the 2de edit

Comment: I didn't see it. As you mentioned in your answer, you had not created a relation between the two entities. And since you had applied a _toString magic method the value given from the Choice field you had created was the title. You did the right thing to make the relation but in case you didn't wanted that relation you could have just created a ChoiceType field and provide an associative array as choices where the key of the value would have been the School Id and the value would have been the name, this way you would have transmitted the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I just created a ManyToOne type relationship between the student and the school (the student can have a school, and the school can have several students)

Answer (score 0):

because of

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->nomAgence;
}
```

try to add **choice_value**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('codeAgence', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Agence::class,
            'label' => 'Agence',
            'required' => true,
            'choice_value'=> 'id'
        ])
    ;
}
```

or like this:

```
'choice_value' => function (?MyOptionEntity $entity) {
    return $entity ? $entity->getId() : '';
},
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-value

**EDITED**

try to call setCodeAgnce in the controller:

```
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $eleve->setCodeAgence($form->get('codeAgence')->getData());

        $this->em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('eleve.index');
    }
```

Comment: I removed the toString function and did this to avoid an error: choice_label' => 'nomAgence'
But now, with the 'choice_value' I have this error: Expected argument of type "string", "object" given to the property path "agencyCode".

Comment: if you remove toString , so you don't need to add choice_value. so try to remove choice_value and inspect the DOM and see if the ids of agences is set as values of <option> or no

Comment: Yes, the ids are correctly defined in the option values

Comment: And if I leave the toString function and add 'choice_value' the value in the database is 0 instead of 5 for example

Comment: I have edited my answer, try to call setCodeAgnce in the controller:

Comment: maybe because of `* @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=2)` of $codeAgence attribute. change it to string and length to 20 for example and update the database

Comment: If I change to a string, it puts the name of the school in the database ...

Comment: @LouisGailleton don't forget to update the database

Comment: My database is already update, but i updated it just in case, and it's change nothing

Comment: try to add `dd($form->get('codeAgence')->getData())` and tell me the output

`if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
  dd($form->get('codeAgence')->getData()) ;
}`

Comment: EleveController.php on line 118:
App\Entity\Agence {#832 ▼
  -id: 5
  -nomAgence: "CER SAINT-FONS 2"
  -adresseAgence: "Saint-Fons 2"
  -forfaits: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#899 ▶}
}

Comment: you use EleveChoixAgenceType in createForm(EleveChoixAgenceType::class, $eleve); but you show us SchoolFormType, you are working on SchoolFormType not on EleveChoixAgenceType  ??!!